# Find third occurrence of a special character and drop everything before that in R

Tags: regex, r, substring

I have this sample vector containing URLs. My goal is to obtain the path of the URL.

```
sample1 <- c("http://tercihblog.com/indirisu/docugard/", "http://funerariagomez.com/js/ggogle/a201209e3f79b740337b7bdb521630fe/", 
      "http://www.t-online.de/contacts/2015/08/atlas.html/", "http://mgracetimber.ie/wp-content/themes/Banner/db/box/", 
      "http://zamartrade.com/cs/DHL/DHL%20_%20Tracking.htm/", "http://dunhamengineering.com/menu/Auto-loadgoogleDrive/Document.Index/", 
      "http://www.indiegogo.com/guide/forum/2014/09/forgot-password/", 
      "http://raetc.com/wp-admin/Service/clients/votre-compte/en-ligne/imp-rem.fr/", 
      "http://www.lidanhang.com/img/?https://secure.runescape.com/m=weblogin/loginform.ws?mod=www&amp;hwjklxlamp;ssl=0&amp;dest/", 
      "http://www.sudaener.com/wp-includes/js/crop/dropbox/", "https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/blocklist.php/", 
      "https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/blocklist.php?download=hostsdeny/", 
      "https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/blocklist.php?download=iptablesblocklist/", 
      "https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/blocklist.php?download=snort/", 
      "https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/blocklist.php?download=squiddomain/"
    )
```

My initial try was this:

```
gsub('http://[^/]+/','/',sample1)
```

However this won't work with URLs that have `https://`. A suitable solution would be to drop everything before the third occurrence of`"/"`. I was wondering how to use `regex`to do this and also if there is a way to do it using `substring`.

Thanks

Comment: maybe `gsub('https?://[^/]+/','/',sample1)` instead ? (`s?` says "s" 0 or 1 time).

Comment: @Cath, yes this will do it as far as regex goes.

Comment: And what goes further than the regex here? :) Is that a solution that works for you?

Comment: Well I was wondering if `substring` would do it also

Comment: There is another way using `strsplit` but, as you can see, `gsub` is much more sensible: `sapply(sample1, function(s) paste0(c('', unlist(strsplit(s, '/'))[-(1:3)]), collapse='/'), USE.NAMES=FALSE)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is really advisable to go with `gsub` here since the code is cleaner and more straightforward.

If you want to remove all before the 3rd `/`, use

```
> gsub('^(?:[^/]*/){3}','/',sample1)
 [1] "/indirisu/docugard/"                                                                              
 [2] "/js/ggogle/a201209e3f79b740337b7bdb521630fe/"                                                     
 [3] "/contacts/2015/08/atlas.html/"                                                                    
 [4] "/wp-content/themes/Banner/db/box/"                                                                
 [5] "/cs/DHL/DHL%20_%20Tracking.htm/"                                                                  
 [6] "/menu/Auto-loadgoogleDrive/Document.Index/"                                                       
 [7] "/guide/forum/2014/09/forgot-password/"                                                            
 [8] "/wp-admin/Service/clients/votre-compte/en-ligne/imp-rem.fr/"                                      
 [9] "/img/?https://secure.runescape.com/m=weblogin/loginform.ws?mod=www&amp;hwjklxlamp;ssl=0&amp;dest/"
[10] "/wp-includes/js/crop/dropbox/"                                                                    
[11] "/blocklist.php/"                                                                                  
[12] "/blocklist.php?download=hostsdeny/"                                                               
[13] "/blocklist.php?download=iptablesblocklist/"                                                       
[14] "/blocklist.php?download=snort/"                                                                   
[15] "/blocklist.php?download=squiddomain/"
```

The `^(?:[^/]*/){3}` matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^/]*/){3}` - exactly 3 occurrences of:

  - `[^/]*` - zero or more characters other than `/`
  - `/` - a literal `/` character.

[Cath suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088337/find-third-occurrence-of-a-special-character-and-drop-everything-before-that-in/35089430#comment57898551_35088337) a more precise your regex fix, but perhaps, you'd like to add `^` at the start to only match at the beginning of the string:

```
gsub('^https?://[^/]+/','/',sample1)
      ^     ^
```

The `?` (greedy) quantifier means *one or zero occurrences*, thus making the `s` after `http` optional. It is identical to (but more efficient than) `gsub('^(https|http)://[^/]+/','/',sample1)`.

You may also want to make your regex case-insensitive, add `ignore.case = TRUE`.